# Getting array instead of dictionary

Tags: json, swift, swift3

I did't use third-party files for calling the API, here is the code:

```
func CallWebService(_ methodType: NSString, methodName: NSString, inputDict: NSDictionary, completion: @escaping (_ result: [String:AnyObject]) -> Void, failure:(_ failurMSG: NSString)->())
{

do {
    let data: Data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: inputDict, options: [])

    //create request
    let tmpString: String = "\(kBaseUrl)\(methodName)"
    let  urlString :String = tmpString.addingPercentEncoding( withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!
    let urlRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: urlString)!)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = methodType as String
    urlRequest.httpBody = data
    urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")


    let task : URLSessionDataTask! = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) in

        if let _ = error
        {
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

            })

        }else{

            do {

                let dict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]

                completion(dict)


            }catch{
            }
        }
    })

    task.resume()

} catch {
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

    })
    failure("Something goes wrong please try again.")
}
```

}

While I'm hitting API I got the below response:

```
["status": success, "category": {
    "file_image" = "http://abcds.com/cphp/26/uploads/pdf1.png";
    "file_name" = "1 \U0645\U0644\U0641 \U0627\U062e\U062a\U0628\U0627\U0631";
    "file_path" = "http://hghg/images/2311201663231Michael20plat20du20jour20correctd.pdf";
    id = 2;
    "sub_name" = "P12 \U0641\U0631\U0639\U064a\U0629";
}]
```

This is not the correct format, what am I missing?

I need the output to be:

```
{"status": success, "category": [
   "file_image" = "http://abcds.com/cphp/26/uploads/pdf1.png";
    "file_name" = "1 \U0645\U0644\U0641 \U0627\U062e\U062a\U0628\U0627\U0631";
    "file_path" = "http://hghg/images/2311201663231Michael20plat20du20jour20correctd.pdf";
    id = 2;
    "sub_name" = "P12 \U0641\U0631\U0639\U064a\U0629";
]
}
```

Comment: I think its problem from server side. tell your PHP guy to change this response

Comment: Your assertions are wrong, and your object is correct. This *is* a dictionary. Try doing `dict["status"]` you'll see. Once you will have cast the AnyObject part to an actual useful type you will see that the remaining of the object is also correct.

Comment: Looks to me like you ARE getting a dictionary. The entry `"Status": success` looks like a key/value pair. How are you displaying your data? You'll get different formatting depending on how you display it, and it won't look like JSON once you've converted it.

Comment: The PHP guy is sending in a correct manner . Will you please tell me is there any mistake in my code

Comment: Can you share url you are hitting?...

Comment: The actual and the expected output are not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you ARE getting a dictionary.

### EDIT:

In fact, the fact that your code is force-casting the JSON data to type `[String:AnyObject]` proves that the results are a dictionary. If they weren't, the force-cast line would crash:

```
let dict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, 
  options: .allowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]
```

(The `as! [String:AnyObject]` part of that line says "I am positive that the value can be cast to the type `[String:AnyObject]`. Please crash my program if not.)

Try adding this to your code:

```
print("dict type =" + String(describing:type(of:dict)))
```

I bet you get

> `dict type = Dictionary<String:AnyObject>`

Comment: Well, OP is doing `as! [String:AnyObject]` so we are indeed sure that what they have is a dictionary, otherwise they would have complained about the infamous fatal error... ;)

Comment: True, but displaying the type of the object is a useful learning tool.

Comment: @DuncanC if i'm writing   completion(String(describing:type(of:dict))) then its giving error like can not convert value of string to expected argument type '[String AnyObject]'

Comment: @DuncanC what should i write in completion to get desired op